# chef Knife command: knife cookbook upload sample when gives error

Tags: chef-infra, knife

knife cookbook upload sample when executed gives following error

> WARNING: No knife configuration file found. See https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html for details.
>   ERROR: Could not find cookbook sample in your cookbook path, skipping it
>   WARN: Failed to read the private key /etc/chef/client.pem: #
>   ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from /etc/chef/client.pem
>
> Check your configuration file and ensure that your private key is readable

- updated time server
- tried changing public key

Comment: Questions about *using* devops tools, vs writing code for them, are a better fit for our sister site [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Whether you re-ask your question there or continue to refine it here, I'd also suggest including information about the presence of `/etc/chef/client.pem` in the question itself (since the error message is giving you a very direct pointer towards that as the immediate problem). Does the file *actually exist*? Is it readable by the account you're currently running as?